# how to compile and run vuforia sample code for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have download the Vuforia SDK and Sample Code from given website but it is giving

`<QCAR/QCAR.h> file not found`

http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality

Comment: Did you put the samples in the right place in the SDK directory?  Is the include path set correctly?

Answer (score 15):

The Vuforia iOS Samples need to be added to the samples directory of the Vuforia iOS SDK installation.

1. Download the Vuforia Samples that come in a compressed archive and expand these into their own directory.
2. Copy the samples into the Vuforia installation directory so that the directory structure looks like this:

> ~/../vuforia-sdk-ios-x-x-xxx/samples/VuforiaSamples/VuforiaSamples.xcodeproj:

Answer (score 4):

For folks like me, who still had issue after adding samples to the SDK folder, pls use the below. The solution was mentioned in the vuforia developer forums(https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/getting-error-lexical-or-prepocessor-issue-qcartoolh) and it helped fix the problem for me.

Step 1:

Copying the build folder (containing the include, lib folders within) in the Project directory.

Step 2:

Link the 'libVuforia.a' to your local build folder copied in the project directory.

Step 3:

and updating the Build Settings for the keys below.

a)  Header Search Paths  =  $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/include

b)  Library Search Paths  =  $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/lib/arm

Comment: Execuse me but what does this mean???

"Link the 'libVuforia.a' to your local build folder copied in the project directory."

Can you provide steps to do it?

Comment: @TatiOverflow - I meant to link the library to the project under 'Linked Libraries and Frameworks' section.

Answer (score 1):

The older answers didn't work for me in Xcode 11. But, this did:

1. Delete the reference to the Vuforia.framework under the Project Navigator and then re-add it under Build Phases > Link With Libraries
2. Add the directory of the framework under Build Settings > Framework Search Paths. In my case, this is `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../build`
3. Embed the Vuforia.framework under Build Phases > Embed Frameworks
4. Created a key after logging into the Vuforia.com website and added it to the `Vuforia::setInitParameters` function call in SampleApplicationSession.mm.
5. Delete "arm" under Build Settings > Architectures > Valid Architectures for both the project and the target.

I hope this helps someone else too.